# Does this UI element exist in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I can't figure out if this element exists in Flutter: a page positioned at the bottom, which can be opened with a swipe up (see screenshots).
It is common in iOS apps but you can see it in android in Google Maps for example.

[Google maps Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY3Dt.jpg)

[IFTTT screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYXxo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this package https://pub.dev/packages/rubber . This works similar to that of your screenshot.